# The same LDA parameters and data input, but I have different topics everytime?

Tags: apache-spark, lda, apache-spark-mllib

I'm using LDA with Spark MLlib framework.
To determine number of topics, I have try: run LDA model with increase number of topics, then find the best number of topic has maximum value log-likelihood.
But if I run again in the same way and the same input data. I have different value of number of topics. So can you help me with two question below:

**What should value I must use to determine number of topics: logLikelihood or logPrior**

**Why does the same LDA parameters and input data generate different topics everytime?**

**And how do I stabilize the topic generation?**

Thanks you very much.

Edit:
I found solution by set seed before run LDA, using:

```
DistributedLDAModel.setSeed(long value)
```

Comment: Can you please show the code you're using to fit your model? In particular, I'd like to know whether you're using `EMLDAOptimizer` or `OnlineLDAOptimizer`.

Comment: In currently, I'm using logLikelihood value to determine what is the best value of `number of topic`.

Comment: Check this link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067734/lda-model-generates-different-topics-everytime-i-train-on-the-same-corpus?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this because LDA uses randomness in both training and inference steps. Try setting the same seed every time.