# Spark LDA - Consistent Topic Distributions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, lda

I'm using Spark's LDA implementation, as shown in example code [here](https://gist.github.com/jkbradley/ab8ae22a8282b2c8ce33). I want to get consistent topics/topic distributions for my training data. I'm training on two machines and would like the output to be the same.

I understand that LDA uses a random component for training/inference, it's explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067734/lda-model-generates-different-topics-everytime-i-train-on-the-same-corpus/15069580#15069580). It looks like consistent results can be achieved in python gensim by setting the seed value manually. I've tried this in Spark but I am still getting slight variance in my outputted topic distributions.

```
ldaParams: LDA = new LDA().setK(10).setMaxIterations(60).setSeed(10L)
val distributedLDAModel: DistributedLDAModel = ldaParams.run(corpusInfo.docTermVectors).asInstanceOf[DistributedLDAModel]
val topicDistributions: Map[Long,Vector] = distributedLDAModel.topicDistributions.collect.toMap //produces different results on each run
```

Is there a way I can get consistent topic distributions for my training set of data?

Comment: What do you mean by _slight_? Can you give estimated order of magnitude.

Comment: I could try to get an estimate, but why does that matter? I'm looking for consistent results. Is that even possible?

Comment: Well, it matters because we work with this ugly thing called FP arithmetics where operations which we expect to be associative and commutative are not. Since every shuffle in Spark introduces a source of non-determinism there is no strong guarantee you'll get exactly the same result with each run even if RNG sequence is deterministic.