# LDA topic modeling changes result everytime I run the code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, lda, topic-modeling

This is my first time using LDA.

As you can see at the title, the result and visualization change everytime I run the code.
Can you tell me how can this happen...??

I'm using python and jupyter notebook.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067734/lda-model-generates-different-topics-everytime-i-train-on-the-same-corpus#:~:text=answer%20was%20accepted%E2%80%A6-,Why%20does%20the%20same%20LDA%20parameters%20and%20corpus%20generate%20different,both%20training%20and%20inference%20steps.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick response!!